# Constructor not being called

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out why I keep getting a null ref on filename when I'm clearly calling this singleton and it should be calling the Logger() to set the filename variable:

```
public class Logger
{
private static Logger defaultLogger = null;
readonly string filename;

public static Logger DefaultLogger
{
    get
    {
        // Check for valid instance
        if (defaultLogger == null) 
            defaultLogger = new Logger();

        // Return instance
        return defaultLogger;
    }
}

private Logger()
{
    filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyLogPath"];
}


    public string Filename
    {
        get { return this.filename; }
    }

    public void Write(EntryType type, string data)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
            //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm calling this class:

```
Logger.DefaultLogger.Write(EntryType.Error, e.ToString());
```

So I get this error during runtime saying that filename is null:

```
 Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path

Source Error:

Line 49: 
Line 50: 
Line 51:        public string Filename
Line 52:        {
Line 53:            get { return this.filename; }
```

This was our original code (I did not write this), same problem:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static Logger DefaultLogger = new Logger();

string filename;

    public Logger()
    {
    filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogPath"];
    }

    public Logger(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public string Filename
    {
        get { return this.filename; }
    }

    public void Write(LogEntryType type, string data)
    {
        lock ()
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
            {
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never use `lock(this)`. See the Remarks section here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx.

Comment: I tested your code and the private constructor is hit

Comment: Wait, now my code fails at this line:

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))

because filename is null, can you set the filename explicitly and see?

Comment: I've updated the original post for more info.

Comment: Yea, it fails at the using statement.  When I call Write, it fails.

Comment: So I tried moving the filename set out of the constructor but it still did not work.  I prefer it in the construcgtor since this is used as a singleton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it because

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyLogPath"];
```

is null?

Check that your `App.Config` file is there ( it takes the form of `yourexe.exe.config` in your bin folder). You App.Config should have the following lines:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="MyLogPath" value="C:\Simple.txt" />
   <appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Maybe in order to test, you can temporary set the filename to a well-know path (     `filename=@"D:\C#\mytext.txt";`) and see whether you get the error or not.

If I set the filename explicitly, then I won't have such an error, OTOH,if I set

```
filename=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyLogPath"];
```

then I will get a

> System.ArgumentNullException : Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: path
>    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String
>   path, Boolean append, Encoding
>   encoding, Int32 bufferSize)  at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String
>   path, Boolean append)

If I stepped using a debugger, I can see that it failed at:

```
(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
```

I don't know why your debugger won't hit the constructor. My debugger hit the constructor in both cases.

Comment: No, because I set a break point there on that line, and it doesn't even get hit.  I know that key is there in the web.config and is valid.

Comment: Does the construct get called from your factory method at all?

Comment: no, I stated that the debug point doesn't get hit if I put a debug point on that line of code inside the constructor that is setting the filename.  So it's like the constructor is not being hit at all.

Comment: sorry, yes it's not finding that key.  If forgot I'm not in a web project.

Comment: but we are grabbing keys like this in other non-web projects so I wonder why this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking into it too much..

```
    private Logger()
    {
        filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyLogPath"];
        throw new Exception("filename = "+filename);
    }
```

Does the exception get thrown?

Comment: no it does not get thrown.  And yes, the calling code is hit by debug.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted the code and replaced

```
filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyLogPath"];
```

with

```
filename = @"test.log";
```

And it works fine. So your error is in the spelling of `"MyLogPath"` or in the `app.config` .

Answer (score 0):

Static initilaizers are executed when the class definition is first accessed, which in your case means they are executed before your private constructor.

Comment: I'm not following.  I call DefaultLogger and it should call the Logger().  Can you explain again?

Comment: Nevermind, you are right, what I said is true, but not relevant. When exactly do you call the Write method? is it possible that you do that before ConfigurationManager is fully initialized. In general static initializers is a tricky business - execution order is implicit and sometimes difficult to predict

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lock, so you expect this to be called in a multithreaded scenario, but you don't synchronize DefaultLogger.  Also, are you sure you're setting fileName to something non-null in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your Logger to instance variable in your client code and accessing it's FileName.  Perhaps it's not getting assigned correctly.
Also, do you need to have filename as  readonly if you're only providing a get property?